# How to fetch object in create method?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Need help on fetching the value in my view method.**

Hello! I'm trying to fetch the value of my requesterid. I want to create a condition that if requesterid is equal to a certain value, it will allow the create method. I don't know how I will access the variable. Can someone help me on this?

I have this in my code so far, but it says that

```
 "Error": "'Request' object has no attribute 'requesterid'"
```

Here's my views.py

```
class RequestListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = requestTable.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RequestCreateSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.requesterid.userroleid == 3:
            write_serializer = RequestCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
            write_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            instance = self.perform_create(write_serializer)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(write_serializer.data)
            return Response({"Request ID": write_serializer.instance.requestid, "Parts ID": [p.partsid for p in write_serializer.instance.parts.all()]},headers=headers)
        raise ValidationError("Sorry! Your role has no permission to create a request.")
```

Here's my models.py

```
class userTable(models.Model):
    userid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default = uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)  
    userroleid = models.ForeignKey(roleTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
class roleTable(models.Model):
    roleid = models.IntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

```
class requestTable(models.Model):
    rid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)   
    requesterid =  models.ForeignKey(userTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
(...)
```

Comment: You're trying to access `requesterid` from `request` object & it does not have that attribute   if your `requesterid` is comming as a data then check `requesterid` inside `request.data`

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Thanks! Do you know how i can get the `userroleid` in my `userTable`? I have tried `serializer = request.data.get('requesterid__userroleid')` then `if serializer == 3:` but it's not going inside my if condition.

Comment: try this `instance.requesterid.userroleid`

Comment: @AnkitTiwari It says `"Error": "local variable 'instance' referenced before assignment"`

Comment: Try this write_serializer.instance.requesterid.userroleid

Comment: I tried this and it catches the validation error. Only problem is the create method strangely proceeds to POSTing the request. It was saved in the database @KrishnaSinghal